# Including only minimal Qt library with a program

Tags: linux, qt, pyqt, size, python-2.x

I have a PyQt program that's apart of package which is only about 9MB. This isn't much of a concern except that the Qt dependencies that get drawn in with it combined are closer to 100MB.

So my question is there any logical and safe way of including only portions of the Qt library that I could include in my package and then no longer include Qt as a dependency, or a smaller alternative to the enormous Qt library that would still be compatible with my code?

Comment: You may want to try building *static* Qt libs and linking with them. You then don't have to include Qt as a dependency. I have no idea whether it will noticeably reduce your package size.

Comment: I agree with n.m. Also, are you building debug binaries? The debug libraries are much bigger than the release libraries.

Comment: @TonyK No, I'm not building the libraries in debug mode.

Comment: @n.m. If I included them as static libs with the package, could I then run through and cut out all the code that I didn't use? That would certainly lower the package size, but I'm unsure of if that would make the GUI unstable.

Comment: Linking with static libraries automatically includes only referenced code, with the granularity level of object file.

Comment: @n.m. But the OP hasn't got any referenced code: his program is written in PyQt.

Comment: @ekhumoro correct. I was thinking that, but wasn't sure if there was just something I had never heard before.

Comment: @josh. Why do you care about the size of the dependencies on linux? The majority of potential users will have qt installed anyway (mainly because of kde). So if you include static libraries in your package, the majority of users will actually end up _worse off_.

Comment: @ekhumoro: oops, missed that. Then it won't work, as there's no linking stage.

Comment: @ekhumoro Becuase the program I've written is going to be included in a linux distro, and thus will be included in the ISO. Some of the editions don't natively run QT but GTK instead, so including this package raises the size of their ISO's by 100MB+. I'm going to be porting the code over to GTK in the future, but until then I was hoping that there might be a way to lower its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing what you want, but if you are using a standard PyQt distro, standard practice is to leave it up to the user to download and install dependencies. This could be automated by having an install script part of your ISO, that determines if pyqt is needed and if not available fetches the pyqt from your site and installs it, or automatically downloads source from riverbank site and attempts to build automatically.

Comment: It is listed as a dependency right now, but this is the problem. The program is being included in an ISO for a distro, but some of their editions don't natively run QT but GTK instead, so adding my program will draw in all the QT dependencies which raises the size of the ISO by 100MB+